# for outer and inner loops using arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Ive been using a azure mobile service back end to manipulated data before it is queried by an app. I have a feed that people can subscribe to an item and get the information from item. the link between the user and the items is in a new table that contains the userid and the itemid. i then do a for loop to find the each  items matching itemid and then do an inner for loop to find all of the items details and take them and put them into a new array for sending.

It only seems to be working when i have the request respond after the inner loop like this. However i only get the item details for one of the subscribed items.

```
var itemfeedcollection = [];
var useritemconnections = tables.getTable('UserItemConnections');
useritemconnections.where({ username : user.userId }).read(
    {
        success: function(results)
        {
            if (results.length > 0)
            {
                for (var itemconnection = 0; itemconnection < results.length; itemconnection++)
                {
                    var items = tables.getTable('Items');
                    items.where({ itemid : results[itemconnection].itemid }).read(
                    {
                        success: function(itemsresults)
                        {
                            if (itemsresults.length > 0)
                            {
                                for(var item = 0; item < itemsresults.length; item++)
                                {
                                    itemfeedcollection.push(itemsresults[item])
                                }
                                request.respond(statusCodes.OK, itemfeedcollection);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                request.respond(400, "We couldn't find any item details for the item you are subscribed to");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                }

            }
            else
            {
                request.respond(400, "You are not subscribed to any items");
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

But if i move the request respond to after then outer loop where its suppose to be I get nothing at all. I would think i would at least get one item.

```
var itemfeedcollection = [];
var useritemconnections = tables.getTable('UserItemConnections');
useritemconnections.where({ username : user.userId }).read(
    {
        success: function(results)
        {
            if (results.length > 0)
            {
                for (var itemconnection = 0; itemconnection < results.length; itemconnection++)
                {
                    var items = tables.getTable('Items');
                    items.where({ itemid : results[itemconnection].itemid }).read(
                    {
                        success: function(itemsresults)
                        {
                            if (itemsresults.length > 0)
                            {
                                for(var item = 0; item < itemsresults.length; item++)
                                {
                                    itemfeedcollection.push(itemsresults[item])
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                request.respond(400, "We couldn't find any item details for the item you are subscribed to");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            request.respond(statusCodes.OK, itemfeedcollection);
            }
            else
            {
                request.respond(400, "You are not subscribed to any items");
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

I am also curious if this is good practice to link items like this. I would also like to add that there maybe up to a few thousand itemconnections meaning that it would do a getTable for each of them. is that a bad thing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears i was right and narrowed it down to the request respond being out side of the items results function. So i called both tables and then did my for loops in the results function then pushed each item to the array and now it is working correctly like this.

```
        var itemfeedcollection = [];
        var useritemconnections = tables.getTable('UserItemConnections');
        useritemconnections.where({ username : user.userId }).read(
        {
            success: function(useritemconnectionsresults)
            {
                if (useritemconnectionsresults.length > 0)
                {
                    var items = tables.getTable('Items');
                    items.read(
                    {
                        success: function(itemsresults)
                        {
                            if (itemsresults.length > 0)
                            {
                                for (var itemconnection = 0; itemconnection < useritemconnectionsresults.length; itemconnection++)
                                {
                                    for (var item = 0; item < itemsresults.length; item++)
                                    {
                                        if (useritemconnectionsresults[itemconnection].itemid == itemsresults[item].itemid)
                                        {
                                            itemfeedcollection.push(itemsresults[item]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                request.respond(200, itemfeedcollection); 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                request.respond(400, "Where have all the items gone");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    });                     
                }
                else
                {
                    request.respond(400, "You are not subscribed any items");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

This is good becuase now I dont have to call the items table thousands of times.